# Question that is clearly not a duplicate linked to my question, marking it as duplicate.

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

I asked a question yesterday: [Coupon collector's problem: mean and variance in number of coupons to be collected to complete a set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3453965/coupon-collectors-problem-mean-and-variance-in-number-of-coupons-to-be-collect)

This asks for the mean and variance of the coupon collector's problem in the general case when the coupons have unequal probability. It has been marked as a duplicate of this one: [Expected time to roll all 1 through 6 on a die](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28905/expected-time-to-roll-all-1-through-6-on-a-die)

My edit clearly explains that I'm asking for the variance in the general case, while the question it is a supposed duplicate of asks only for the mean and that too in the special case of the coupons having equal probabilities.

So, the first question is not a duplicate of the one linked to it for sure. For this reason, I wanted the duplicate tag to be removed if possible.

I did ask a similar question myself in another post a few weeks ago here: [Coupon collectors problem: variance calculation missing a term.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3439096/coupon-collectors-problem-variance-calculation-missing-a-term)

However, I wish to delete that post (the only answer there is my own) and want people to refer to this one since it is much more comprehensive.

In any case, the current question linked there is clearly more limited in scope along multiple dimensions.

Comment: Thanks @XanderHenderson. I posted an answer there. Is it ok to delete my other question which has an answer only from me?

Comment: Since the old question is entirely your working, if you are convinced that keeping it around doesn't add anything beyond the new question it would be okay for you to delete it. If you decide to delete it, first unaccepting your answer, then deleting the answer and finally deleting the question avoids the system raising a pop-up asking whether you _really_ want to delete an answered question.